# Remove Google Search Bar on Nexus devices running on stock Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-now, stock-rom, google-search

I have been reading for days about how to remove the Google Search Bar from the top of my Nexus 6 since I never use it. I have gotten mixed answers on exactly what file to delete and where it is.

I have heard `quicksearchbar.apk` but it's not in `/system/app` like in previous versions. Does anybody know where the file/files are I need to delete in order to get rid of the search bar, or else, how to remove it? Preferably not downloading another launcher, since I don't want to bloat my phone when I could reduce the size.

Comment: My apologies, I answered but Xposed won't work in ART and that's the only runtime in Lollipop. Really then Nova may well be the way to go. It's a third of the size of the Google Now launcher, so I'd install Nova and get rid of Google Now Launcher and you'll actually gain space.

Comment: @RossC I know it's old, but AFAIK Xposed is somewhat supported on Lollipop again. Probably your answer could work now?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a third-party launcher app like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en). In Nova Launcher, you can hide the persistent search bar by navigating to : Go to `Nova Settings > Desktop > Persistent Search Bar > Select "None"`.

Answer (score 0):

I heard you can go to  Settings >> Apps >> select all apps tab -> find and click "Google Search" and disable it, then reboot. However this will disable all Google search functions.

Otherwise you may be stuck with the alternate launcher option.

Comment: In 5.0 Lollipop the "Disable" button is grayed out when going to Settings > Apps > All...I can force stop but that obviously does nothing. I KNOW there is an .apk file I can delete with the terminal, posibbly Velvet.apk and Velvet.odek but I'm just not positive which file/files to delete, and don't want to brick my phone without being positive.

Comment: @WillHughes I have the disable option in Lollipop 5.0.1 here, however, removing all that functionality may be a bad option.

Comment: I got my phone about a week ago and rooted it, is there already an update to lollipop 5.0? If so how do I go about updating my rooted phone without undoing the changes. I heard with custom recovery and bootloader etc its dangerous to update things

Comment: @RossC - Did you do anything special to get that diable option? I have a rooted device with 5.0.1 and it's greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Nova Prime launcher. It totally changed my home page but did remove the bar and the google cards page too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to remove it in this case:

- No Nova installation nor any other issues with launcher installation
- No "three dots method" as they don't appear on my screen
- No apparently root needed
- No apk removal

I found the way (in my Spanish interface):

1. Ajustes -> Aplicaciones -> Todas -> Aplicacion Google -> Borrar Caché / Borrar Valores por defecto
2. Ajustes -> Aplicaciones -> Todas -> Launcher3 -> Borrar Datos / Borrar Caché / Borrar Valores por defecto

Sorry if I make a mistake in direct translation but I really don't know how it appears in English interface:

1. Settings -> Apps -> all -> Google App -> Remove cache / Remove defaults
2. Settings -> Apps -> all -> Launcher3 -> Remove data / Remove cache / Remove defaults

I use katkiss ROM - Lollipop 5.1 on an Asus Transformer TF101. Hope this works as it worked for me!

Comment: The problem is... you're using custom ROM and different device (but at least you mention it). Also, there's no `Launcher3` on Nexus devices.

Answer (score -1):

I know how irritating it is to see this Google bar. You don't need anything to remove it. Just tap on your home screen in the middle of the screen. The bottom options open up showing wallpaper, widgets etc. Just above those options is the tiny dots. Click on those dots and you'll see that the first option is to remove the search bar.
Hope you enjoy your clean home screen with this :)

Gaurav

Comment: I followed your instructions and I do not have anything that lets me remove it like you are talking about. Are you using the Stock Google Now Launcher? That is what is used by default on a Nexus 6.

Comment: On Android 5.1.1 (CM 12.1)  this method works. Long press on home screen, in the bottom there are wallpapers, widgets, settings. Above them there are  3 dots in a sort of triangular shape. You can disable the search bar from there.

Answer (score -2):

for turning Google search bar OFF, hold finger in screen, swipe up the 3dots up the widgets button, in the top of page you can turn search bar off.
was it as easy as it looked?

Comment: Probably you need to provide more info on this (e.g. device model? custom ROM?). On my device (Nexus 4, stock Lollipop 5.0.1), long-pressing the home screen will show "select wallpaper" on stock launcher, or "wallpapers, widgets, and settings" on Google Now Launcher. No 3-dot on the widget button, etc.

Comment: @AndrewT. Maybe he meant tap-and-hold *inside the search bar* – i.e. the element you want to "modify" (read: kick)? Could you verify that? I've got no Lolli, so I can't. I usually removed it that way: tap-and-hold, then move it to trash :)

Comment: @Izzy just tried that, but the search bar is not a standard widget you can remove and add. I think it's the same for stock Android ROM since.. I dunno, but at least JB, when I got Nexus 4.