# change the position of google search bar in Google Now Launcher

Tags: launcher, google-now, google-search

I am using [Google now](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) launcher on my Moto G3 phone. I have set up wallpapers on my home screen but the Google search bar(which is situated at top of my home screen), seems to be always overlapping the wallpaper content.

Ideally, I should be able to get rid of that search bar from my home screen of Google Now launcher, but it looks like [there is no easy/working way](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89741/remove-google-search-bar-on-nexus-devices-running-on-stock-lollipop) to do it, beside installing another launcher, which I do not want to do.

So, as other alternative, I want to adjust the position of Google search bar by moving it around the home screen. But I am unable to drag/move it and hence unable to change its location

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're into rooting and Xposed Framework, this module called [Xposed GEL Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) has a bunch of Now Launcher-related settings, among which you can disable the permanent search bar. You can then put a search bar widget on arbitrary location of the screen.

Note that this app requires a compatible version of Now Launcher / Google App to work at all. Supported versions are listed on the module description page.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is not. But if you are looking for another Google made launcher, get the one made for Google Pixel phones by going to [1] and downloading it. Then go to your settings, go to security, then enable installation of apps from unknown sources. After the launcher is installed press home, choose Pixel Launcher and set it as default. You can now disable the setting that was enabled above.

[1] http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/pixel-launcher/pixel-launcher-7-1-1-3368800-release/pixel-launcher-7-1-1-3368800-android-apk-download/